# encoding given input using prolog

Tags: prolog

```
count([_],[],1).    
count(H,[H1|T],N):- count(H1,T,N1),(H = H1 -> N is N1+1 ; H \=H1 -> N is 1).   

encode([]).
encode([H|T]):- count(H,T,N1),encode(T),write("["),write(N1),write("],").
```

---

Above is my Prolog code to count and print the consecutive occurrence of the letters and giving the out put in desired manner.
For example if 
Sample Input:

```
?- encode("555555577777777199999111111").
```

should return

```
Encoded Output:
[7,5],[8,7],1,[5,9],[1,6]
```

Comment: my out put is always false

Comment: By the way, it's better to edit the question than leave comments on the question.

Comment: Your output statements are, `write("["),write(N1),write("],")` which means there's no way it's going to look like, `[7,5],[8,7],1,[5,9],[1,6]` just on the basis of output formatting alone. So you might want to think through that more carefully.

Comment: `write/1` won't fail, and your recursive call to `encode(T)` is fairly harmless and will eventually succeed at `encode([])`. That tells me tha tyour `count(H, T, N1)` is failing at some point. I would suggest debugging `count` separately before tackling `encode`. HINT: It looks like the first argument to `count` is a list element, but your `count` base case assumes it's a list `[_]`.

Comment: There's a type problem in that the base case for `count/3`, the first argument is a list, but it's an element everywhere else. Fixing that only produces one solution though.

Comment: I think instead of *writing* output, it might be better to (at least for now) construct a list (like `[[7,5],[8,7],1,[5,9],[1,6]]`) then later you still can write that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### code given below

findnext(H,[],H).

findnext(H,[H|T],[]):- T = [].

findnext(H,[H1|T],[H1|T]):- H \= H1.

findnext(H,[H|T],X):- findnext(H,T,X1),append(X1,[],X).

count([_],[],1).

count(H,[H|T],2):- T = [].

count(H,[H1|_],1):- H \= H1,!.

count(H,[H|T],N):- count(H,T,N1), N is N1+1.

encode([]):- !.

encode([H|T]):-count(H,T,N1),write("["),write(H),write(","),write(N1),write("],"),findnext(H,T,X),encode(X).

str_encode(S) :- atom_chars(S,X),encode(X).

### ends

a new code on all of your valuable suggestion but the problem of printing only 1 instead of [1,1] is hard for me also my new code always ignores the last entry and gives a false as output i would request you to check my new code so there is still scope of improvement but atleast this code works .